# Can't re-instantiate/respawn object I've destroyed in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've 2 scripts. 1 makes objects and the other destroys them.

I first press `OnSave` button which runs script #1 and creates my objects. (there's more than one, although here in the script just shows one, I shortened for the sake of question)

then I press `OnReset` button which destroys created objects/prefabs. But when I press `OnSave` again, it doesn't recreated objects.

These 2 scripts are attached to 2 different gameObjects

here's what I have:

script #1:

```
public GameObject go;
public static volatile List<GameObject> prefab = new List<GameObject>();


public class OnSave : MonoBehaviour
{
public void Start2()
{
                var newObj = Instantiate(go);
                newObj.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("MOOSE").transform;
                newObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
                newObj.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(1.0,1.0,1.0)
                prefab.Add(newObj);


}
}
```

script #2

```
public class OnReset: MonoBehaviour
{
foreach (GameObject obj in prefab)
{
Destroy(obj);
}
}
```

I'm using the latest version of Unity. I have to destroy these objects and recreate them

Comment: What type is your `prefab` variable? Is it just a collection (if so, "prefab" is a bad name for it). Also, is there a chance your "MOOSE" `GameObject` is being destroyed by `OnReset` ?

Comment: @Foggzie it's of type list. yeah that's what i'm thinking

Answer (score 4):

You need a prefab to be able to reinstantiate the object, but the operation of destroying and reinstantiating is heavy, so normally you use a pooling manager of sort like https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/47242 (disclaimer: I'm the author of this one) or https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/23931.

Here's the official Unity totorial about pooling objects: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling

Comment: This is a poorly formed answer but it is correct, still get the plus one but add some code in the future please

Comment: @johnny5, thank you for the +1. I thought about adding a sample but I ended up with a complex code sample that might be confusing to an user that doesn't know about pooling and prefabs (that would seem the case here). If you think it'd be helpful I'll add it anyway ;)

Comment: Nah, Once you get the flow of things down its fine.   It would be a lot of work to put that whole tutorial in, when the link you provided should work fine

Comment: @GiuseppeDeFrancesco but what am I doing wrong? also what if i don't want to use pooling?

Comment: @2222 Well, to reinstantiate the object all you have to do is to take the prefab assigned to "go" and instantiate it anew, but is bad practice in Unity to do so (see the official tutorial I pointed out). If you have 2 uGUI buttons pointing at those method it works the first time for sure, but you are destroying ALL the GameObjects in the scene in the OnReset, therefore the OnSave won't exist any longer, making it impossible to instantiate a new object.

Comment: Correction, you destroy all objects in prefab... so there is nothing to instantiate any longer.

Comment: @GiuseppeDeFrancesco but isn't my OnSave() re-create those prefabs? any way I can fix this without using pooling?

Comment: @2222 Yes, but is unclear when or what you call... really you should use a pool manager :)